# Scala build process

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, development-environment, scalatest

First some context:
My aim is to use scala alongside a testing environment, preferably in an ide.
At first I installed scala (v. 2.10.1) and sbt and it worked. I used emacs and a shell.
Then I wanted to use eclipse and installed the sbt plugin. But when I tried the FlatSpec example of the scalatest website together with the scalatest lib, it did compile but 0/0 tests did run.
In intellij I tried the same example but although I gave my sdk location, the collection package wasn't found.

My problem:
I don't understand what I have to tell my ide or what I have to write (maybe files for maven or make etc.) or where I can learn all that.

My question:
What has the ide to know if I want to run a scala project?
- location of sdk, jdk, sbt, my_project, ... 
- versions of scala, java etc.

What else must it know?

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: 14.0.1 (ultimate edition)

Comment: you should be good. I think everything is built into and you don't need any extra plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ has build in support for sbt projects. My work flow is the following :

Create a project (in the shell) using sbt. Basically you have to create a `build.sbt` and the necessary directory structure

```
`src/main/scala`
`src/main/resources`
`src/test/`
```

The in IntelliJ just do Open -> select build.sbt.

Also check auto-import checkbox.

Everything should work after this.

NOTE: You may have to install the Scala and sbt plugin for the above to work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out as soon as I can. Haven't checked the auto-import box...

Comment: I was so convinced, that the test folder is on the same level as the src folder, but it was not. My fault, thanks for the hint. Now everything works out.